# QT program crashing when using the extern keyword

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to use a global object for different classes using the extern keyword but this somehow doesn't work in QT.

Basically I wanted to create a common GraphicsScene Object to draw rectangles in the same scene but in different classes. That's why I thought a global object "scene_" would be a good choice here.

**manwindow.cpp** :

```
QGraphicsScene *scene_ = new QGraphicsScene();

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene_->setSceneRect(-300,-300,600,600);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene_);

    QGraphicsRectItem *rectItem = new QGraphicsRectItem();
    rectItem->setRect(0,0,200,200);

    scene_->addItem(rectItem);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

***mainwindow.h***:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QGraphicsScene>

#include <QMainWindow>

extern QGraphicsScene *scene_;

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    
    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();
    
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    };
    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here I wanted to retrieve the same object pointer _scene from mainwindow.h  and add a second rectangle to it.

**A.c** :

```
    #include "a.h"
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QGraphicsRectItem>
    
    A::A()
    {
        QGraphicsRectItem *rectItem2 = new QGraphicsRectItem();
        rectItem2->setRect(0,0,200,200);
        scene_->addItem(rectItem2);
    }
```

**main.cpp** :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The program crashes immediately when running it. (Due to the keyword implementation)

```
10:17:26: The program has unexpectedly finished.
10:17:26: The process was ended forcefully.
Desktop_Qt_6_2_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\test.exe crashed.
```

How do I fix this issue or is there another way to implement this?

Comment: It hasn't been created yet. Better would be passing it around, e.g. in the constructor of A. But if you want to fix this, you could do: if (!scene_) scene_ = new QGraphicsScene(); and QGraphicsScene *scene_ = nullptr; in mainwindow.cpp

Comment: This is extremely bad design. Do not do it. Be explicit about the dependencies of your classes and objects. The error you see is only a consequence of this bad design.

Comment: I thought that too but I'm somehow blocked and don't know how to redesign it. Is there a way that allows me to modify the same scene instantiated in class mainwindow and could modify the same one in other classes without using the global pointer.

Comment: Pass the pointer from the `MainWindow` to the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

For your design will work singleton holding common resources (i.e. scene).

The better idea is to declare scene as private member of MainWindow with getter, or even better provide addItem() as public function:

```cpp
void MainWindow::addItem(QGraphicsItem *item)
{
    scene->addItem(item);
}
```